# Unable to set data for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to set data to my highchart with a fetch function but the dta is not displayed or even set to my chart element.

Here is my fetch function

```
fetch("data.csv")
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then((response) => {
       //console.log("d"+response)

       function csvToArray(str, delimiter = ",") {
    let array = str.split("\n").map(function (line) {
        return line.split(delimiter);
    });

    return array;
}


let array = csvToArray(response);

array.splice(0, 1);
array.splice((array.length-1),1)
let string =JSON.stringify(array);
let stringnew = string.replaceAll("\"","");


//console.log(csvToArray(response));
//console.log(csvToArray(response)[0]);
console.log(stringnew);
chart.series[0].setData(stringnew);

   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

as well as my data.csv file

```
time,data
1672683118394,12.00
1672683159084,10.00
1672683199305,9.00
```

I also see in the console the right output

```
[[1672683118394,12.00],[1672683159084,10.00],[1672683199305,9.00]]
```

its corrosponding to the Highcharts doku as I understood. But the data is not loaded.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can you please provide a working example on a site such as jsfiddle? This will include your csv, fetch, and Highcharts configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`stringnew` is a string not a JSON object.

The issue is solved by using

```
JSON.parse(stringnew)
```